# Sending an Array as content of a email

Tags: android, email

Is it somehow possible to pass a array as a content of a email ?

What I'm trying :

This is all in a `onClick` method

Getting the "EditText fields" first

```
EditText tbLocation = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.tbLocation);
```

Creating a string out of it

```
String tbLocationMessage = tbLocation.getText().toString();
```

And then trying to send a email

```
Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {});
                email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Near Miss Report");
                email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, new String []{tbLocationMessage,tbFuActionMessage,tbImActionMessage,tbIssueToRaiseMessage});

                // need this to prompts email client only
                email.setType("message/rfc822");

                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email,
                        "Choose an Email client :"));

            }
```

When I set some breakpoints my arrays are all filled with the text that I entered in the text fields. But then when I choose my email client ("Gmail") Compose text field is empty...

Why is this happening ?

Comment: Try passing actual text string  in line               email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, new String []{tbLocationMessage,tbFuActionMessage,tbImActionMessage,tbIssueToRaiseMessage}); instead of passing a object reference.

Comment: @Techfist well for sure this will work when I pass only one string .. but I want to pass more then one and I have to put them in some bundle or Array etc.. Or do I get you wrong and if yes I'm sry

Comment: then concat them and pass, whats the issue there?

Comment: @Techfist ohh man I feel so bad such an easy solution .. I'm sorry for wasting your time but still THX !!

Answer (score 2):

Use the below code snippet to get String object from the array of String and pass it in

```
private String getMyStringMessage(String[] arr){
   StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
   for(String s : arr) {
     builder.append(s);
   }
   return builder.toString();
}

email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, getMyStringMessage(yout_string_array));
```

Answer (score 0):

Intent.EXTRA_TEXT should be a CharSequence, not an array of strings.  Try concatenating them, rather than making an array of them.  See: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_TEXT